# Creating a new string made of every other character of a given array, and returns it

Tags: java

Need to create a method in which, given a string, a new string will be made and returned formed out of every other character in the original string.

```
public static String everyOther(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i+=2){ 
        result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String G = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    System.out.println(everyOther(G));
}
```

Comment: and the question is...

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<A.length; i+=2){ ` where are you getting `A` from ?

Comment: Please make your question clearer, explain what you want to do, what research you've done and what the program does. Add more details by editing your post.  [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17502049)

Answer (score 0):

Your `everyOther` method should read

```
public static String everyOther(String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i+=2){ 
        result += str.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your for loop was slightly off (see my comment on OP), and there is no need to print out your result ehre as you do that in your main function - unless ofcourse you wanted to print it out twice